# java source code minifier?

Tags: java, minify

Is there a tool out there for minifying java source code?

I am aware there is not much practical need for such a tool, but I am interested to reduce some students' code to 'bare bones' to show how their variable names are interpreted (sort-of -- it will heopfully re-enforce that their choice of variable names are disregarded) by the compiler.  (The next step in this pedagogical process might be to show them the compiled code).

Thanks.

Comment: For Java _source_?  I don't know of any.  ProGuard deals with bytecode.

Comment: I'm not so sure that would be such a good example of how the compiler interprets variable names.

Comment: A similar question was already discussed here: stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator Like @dystroy said, Progard is the most popular one.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154553/how-to-obfuscate-code-without-compiling-the-project

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967987 is also related. In particular, http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/ seems to be a good base for this kind of source-to-source transformation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the java world we mostly speak, due to the purpose, of obfuscation (even if in my opinion the impact on application file size can be useful, I used it a lot on Android applications a few years ago).

The best java obfuscator is probably [Progard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). Like all of them, it can reduce all (non exported) class and/or variable names to just a letter, which is part of the obfuscation as well as part of a minification.

You will have to [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) the bytecode afterwards if you want to show some java.

Comment: Can I use Progard for commercial product?

Comment: ProGuard optimizes/obfuscates bytecode and not Java source.